# Insert bytes into Oracle table using python, Airflow

Tags: python, oracle, byte, airflow, cx-oracle

I want to insert data with type(bytes) into Oracle table into column raw(16) using Python.

INFO - this is data which I want to insert:

**('1', "'test'", "to_date('2021-09-28 15:31:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", b'\xb5V\xad\x04E\xd3V\x1b\x04B\xedL]~W\xf5')**

But I have errors

```
sql = f"INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO {table} {target_fields} VALUES  ({','.join(values)})"
```

> TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bytes found

This is my code:

```
def get_md5(d):
       b = pickle.dumps(d)
        return hashlib.md5(b).digest()
    
for row in rows:
    i += 1
    lst = []
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell, str):
            lst.append("'" + str(cell).replace("'", "''") + "'")
        elif cell is None:
            lst.append('NULL')
        elif isinstance(cell, float) and numpy.isnan(cell):  # coerce numpy NaN to NULL
            lst.append('NULL')
        elif isinstance(cell, numpy.datetime64):
            lst.append("'" + str(cell) + "'")
        elif isinstance(cell, datetime):
            lst.append(
                "to_date('" + cell.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"
            )
        else:
            lst.append(str(cell))
    lst.append("to_date('" + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')")
    s = get_md5(lst)
    lst.append(s)
    
    values = tuple(lst)

    print('values', values)
    sql = f"INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO {table} {target_fields} VALUES  ({','.join(values)})"
    print(sql)
    cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Never build an SQL query using string concatenation. Use a prepared statement `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` and then use bind variables to pass the values.

Comment: @MT0 it is default Oracle_Hook scrpt in Airflow. I just wanted to add extra BYTES column

Comment: As being more performant for the DML statements, prefer using `executemany` rather than `execute`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Ok. but my problem is inserting bytes with string into table

Comment: consider that as a side note, not directly related to your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html). Something like this:

```py
def get_md5(d):
       b = pickle.dumps(d)
        return hashlib.md5(b).digest()
    
for row in rows:
    i += 1
    lst = [cell for cell in row]
    lst.append(get_md5(lst))
    
    print('values', lst)

    sql = (
        f"INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO {table} {target_fields}"
        f" VALUES ({','.join([f':{field}' for field in target_fields])})"
    )

    print(sql)

    cur.execute(sql, lst)
```

As the linked documentation states:

> Using bind variables is important for scalability and security. They help avoid SQL Injection security problems because data is never treated as part of an executable statement. **Never concatenate or interpolate user data into SQL statements.**

*(Emphasis mine)*

Comment: Thank you!
I changed my code. And now insert looks like this 
`INFO - INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO DWH_STAGE2.ZZ_TEST_ARFLOW  (REGION_ID, REGION_NAME, S$CHANGE_DATE, S$MD5) VALUES  (:REGION_ID, :REGION_NAME, :S$CHANGE_DATE, :S$MD5)`
But I have same problems TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bytes found
`ins_r = ', '.join(lst)
cur.execute(sql, ins_r)` when I want to execute it